# What is the Redis key for a queue in Sidekiq?

Tags: sidekiq

I would like to use Datadog to monitor the queue length of some background jobs.

Basically **I need to know the name of the key that represents a queue in Sidekiq**, so that I can monitor it as described here:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/redisdb/

[I've read](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/pull/1153#issuecomment-151159878) that the Sidekiq keys have the form `sidekiq:queue:myqueuename`.

However I have tried to execute `KEYS *myqueuename*` and I can't find anything.
I have also tried to search `KEYS *sidekiq*` but I don't get anything.
If I search `KEYS *queue*` I get the key `queues` which represents a set with the names of the queues (e.g. deliveries, default, low). However those are only the names: I need the actual queues. **What is the key of a queue?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
queue:default
```

is the name of the default queue.  As you state, it is "queue:$NAME" but namespaces (if you use them (please don't)) will also prefix the key.

Comment: That's correct. However **if there isn't any job in queue** (and that is almost always true if you have many background workers) **then the key is not present**! That's the reason why I could not find the keys in production using `KEYS *queue*`.